# Setting up a mail server to simply be able to see emails sent

Tags: smtp

I'm writing an application right now that simply sends emails. All I'd like to be able to do is see clearly that my application is, in fact, sending email and that I'm getting the included attachment. Is there a utility SMTP mail server which will help me do this without actually sending the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! Python rocks!

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```